# Qual a diferença entre Varchar e Varchar2?

Tags: oracle

Tenho uma dúvida em relação aos tipos de dados no oracle:

No Oracle, Qual é a diferença entre varchar e varchar2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**VARCHAR**
Atualmente (até a versão 11G do Oracle Database), `VARCHAR` nada mais é do que um sinônimo para `VARCHAR2` (desde o Oracle8), por isso a **Oracle recomenda não utilizar** este tipo de dado.

Existe a possibilidade de `VARCHAR` ser utilizado em versões futuras para ter uma semântica ou característica diferente de `VARCHAR2`, mas mesmo, estando tudo igual atualmente, utilize `VARCHAR2` ao invés de `VARCHAR`, para evitar possíveis problemas futuros.

**VARCHAR2**
`VARCHAR2` armazena caracteres alfanuméricos de tamanho variável, entre `1` e `4000 bytes` ou caracteres. O tamanho padrão desta coluna é especificado em `bytes`.

Agora vem a pergunta, **qual a diferença entre armazenar bytes ou caracteres**?
Quando utilizamos caracteres `multibyte`, como por exemplo `UTF-8` (para representar caracteres específicos em múltiplas linguagens), `1` único caractere pode ser armazenado em até `3 bytes`. Nestes casos, uma palavra contendo caracteres especiais, como por exemplo, FÁBIO, poderá ter mais `bytes` do que caracteres (a letra `Á`, internamente será armazenada em `2` ou `3 bytes`), por isso, recomenda-se, nestes casos, especificar o armazenamento da coluna em caracteres, ao invés de `bytes`.

<sup>Fonte: [Qual tipo de dado devo usar: CHAR, VARCHAR ou VARCHAR2?](http://www.fabioprado.net/2011/08/qual-tipo-de-dado-devo-usar-char.html)</sup>

Comment: O UTF-8 pode usar até 4 bytes, não 3. Não sei se o mesmo ocorre no Oracle, mas no MySQL existem até dois tipos, o UTF8 e o UTF8MB4, o segundo é o completo, até 4 bytes.

Comment: Tem mais alguma diferença?